# Magento 2 module is still not enabled after running commands

Tags: magento2.4, installation, third-party-module

After uploading a third party module under app/code/ folder, I executed these commands in terminal to install it in the magento system:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-contet:deploy
```

But, when checking status, the module is still not installed. What am I missing in the above
process?

Comment: Are you uploaded registration.php in module root?

Answer (score 0):

You might just need to enable the module first.

`bin/magento module:enable Module_Name`

This will update your config.php file and activate the module.

You can check your module status in the data table `setup_module`

Comment: thank you. This is correct answers, I did then it worked. Unfortunately, I don't have reputation to vote your answer